# Unfold Data by Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a dataset that looks like this (where the codes of ID1 and ID2 can never be the same. So putting them together they are still unique):

| ID | ID1 | Name | AGE | ID2 | Primary | Secondary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | Jim | 34 | 1111 | Mars | A |
| 2 | 1234 | Tom | 24 | 1111 | Mars | A |
| 3 | 1234 | Rick | 55 | 1112 | Mars | B |
| 4 | 2222 | Ann | 22 |  | Jupiter |  |
| 5 | 2222 | Liz | 54 | 3000 | Jupiter | A |
| 6 | 2222 | Frey | 19 | 3000 | Jupiter | A |

What I want to do is for each person that has a value in ID2 I want to add this person at the bottom and want to exchange ID1 with ID2 and Primary with Secondary entries. So in the view that I want to create the entries above would be followed with this entries here:

| ID | ID1 | Name | AGE | ID2 | Primary | Secondary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 1111 | Jim | 34 | 1111 | A | A |
| 8 | 1111 | Tom | 24 | 1111 | A | A |
| 9 | 1112 | Rick | 55 | 1112 | B | B |
| 10 | 3000 | Liz | 54 | 3000 | A | A |
| 11 | 3000 | Frey | 19 | 3000 | A | A |

I tried a lot of things. Like creating separate temp tables for the ID2 values but I just cannot come up with an idea to finish this.
Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: is column `ID` an identity column ?

Comment: For the view it does not have to be. I added it for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
Select ID,ID1,Name,ID2,Primary,Secondary From Tab1
UNION ALL
Select ID,ID2 as ID1 ,Name,ID2,Secondary AS Primary,Secondary From Tab1
WHERE ID2 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is just insert the rows back to the table

```
INSERT INTO tbl ( ID1 , Name , AGE , ID2 , Primary , Secondary )
SELECT ID2 , Name , AGE , ID2 , Secondary , Secondary
FROM   tbl
WHERE  ID2 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I want that only for the view. I do not want to add the data to the existing table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a query to define a vew from you could do the following.

It's not completely clear how you want to generate the ID value but the following will produce your desired results:

```
select ID, ID1, [Name], AGE, ID2, [Primary], [Secondary]
from t
union all
select  max(id) over() + Row_Number() over (order by id)ID, 
    ID2, [Name], AGE, ID2, [Secondary], [Secondary]
from t
where id2 is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid querying the data twice, you can unpivot inside an `APPLY`

```sql
CREATE VIEW YourView
AS
SELECT
  t.ID,
  v.ID1,
  t.Name,
  t.ID2,
  v.Primary,
  t.Secondary
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    SELECT ID1, Primary
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID2, Secondary
    WHERE ID2 IS NOT NULL
) v

GO
```